# How to burn iso to a CF card?

Tags: iso

Slax Linux installation file is only available in .iso format. 
How to burn it to a Compact Flash card?
It also uses KDE, I think GNOME 2 or MATE might be more light weight. I want to install it on a one board computer, namely a PC Engine ALIX board.

Comment: It's related to your iso. For esxample ubuntu iso capable to install to usb flash, you can try with it. But if you want to make same iso, your should do a proccess.Every distro has a same docs.

Comment: What I understand from your comment is that some .iso files are burnable on a CF card just like they are burnable on a USB Flash drive. Did I get you right?

Comment: http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Install_To_CompactFlash

Comment: http://www.parkytowers.me.uk/thin/Linux/TinycoreCF.shtml

Comment: http://julian.coccia.com/article-37.html

Comment: http://deepgeek.us/running-linux-on-compact-flash.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19045-01/blade.x6440/820-3962-11/chap_CF.html